# PHP Why does my foreach loop only give 1 result?

Tags: php, variables, pdo, foreach

Why does my foreach only show 1 result and why not both results, since it clearly shows in my database there are 2 results with Com_Id 1 but still it only gives me 1 result. This is how my Database looks like [image: database]

this are the results that I get

[image]

```
$id = $_GET['view'];
```

Mycode:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM IA_Monitor WHERE Com_ID = :id";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $mon_comid = $row['Com_ID'];
        $mon_barcode[0] = $row['Barcode'];
        $mon_merk = $row['Merk'];
        $mon_type = $row['Type'];
        $mon_inch = $row['Inch'];
        $mon_a_dat = $row['Aanschaf_dat'];
        $mon_a_prijs = $row['Aanschaf_waarde']; 
    }
$monnewDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($mon_a_dat));
if($id==$mon_comid){
foreach($mon_barcode as $key => $value){
    ?>
    <title><?php echo $value; ?></title>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Monitorbarcode: </td><td><?php echo $value;?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Merk: </td><td><?php echo $mon_merk;?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Type: </td><td><?php echo $mon_type;?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Inch: </td><td><?php echo $mon_inch;?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Aanschaf datum: </td><td><?php echo $monnewDate;?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Aanschaf waarde: </td><td><?php echo "&euro;".number_format((float)$mon_a_prijs, 2, '.', '')."";?></td></tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}}else{
    echo "<i>Geen monitoren gevonden</i>";
}
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it doesnt work and could you maybe help me understand and help me with fixing this?

Comment: you are getting all the rows, but you are not adding them to an array, you keep overwriting `$mon_*` vars w/ the last record.

Comment: Alright I see what you mean, let me try to fix it myself first, otherwise I don't learn anything from it ;)

Comment: While you're at it, you can remove the `if($id==$mon_comid)` statement, since it's pretty redundant in this context. You're only fetching records with that `Com_ID`. SQL knows what it's doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you have to define the variables in your while loop. The following saves you some lines of code and if your DB fieldnames are clear, your code won't be a mess:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM IA_Monitor WHERE Com_ID = :id";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$value = count($rows);
if ($value != 0)
foreach($rows as $row){
    $monnewDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['Aanschaf_dat']));
    ?>
    <title><?php echo $value; ?></title>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Monitorbarcode: </td><td><?php echo $row['Barcode'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Merk: </td><td><?php echo $row['Merk'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Type: </td><td><?php echo $row['Type'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Inch: </td><td><?php echo $row['Inch'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Aanschaf datum: </td><td><?php echo $monnewDate; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Aanschaf waarde: </td><td><?php echo "&euro;".number_format((float)$row['Aanschaf_waarde'], 2, '.', '')."";?></td></tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}else{
    echo "<i>Geen monitoren gevonden</i>";
}
```

This code should work. Add the values to an array like $rows here

Comment: It is, you missed some brackets and this won't help fix my problem tho

Comment: Ah the brackets, for sure. Let me fix this

Comment: I think the first problem was the `$query->fetch()` thing. should be fetchAll. Second was that there was one bracket that did nothing. Matter op copy and paste the original code and then merging it.

Comment: True I removed the bracket and add one but i didnt change the fetch, this works now btw thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Good luck with your further codings fellow dutchie :)

Comment: I think you need edit  $query->fetch to $query->fetchAll and $mon_barcode[0] = $row['Barcode']; to  $mon_barcode[] = $row['Barcode'];

Comment: You're right about the `$query->fetchAll`. The second part about the Barcode is not in my solution

Comment: Iterating the data from `fetchAll()` in the same layer is not recommended.  If you intend to iterate the data straight away, then make `fetch()` calls.